# Program freezes when opening 2 consoles using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe, freeze

I'm trying to make a program in C, and I have to open another console with other program on it, when I do that, the first program freezes until I close the second one. I've been looking for answers with no result.

This is the code where I know it fails.

```
system("setterm -term linux -back white -fore black -clear");
char line[LEN];

system("cd ~/Desktop/ && gcc -o Rover Rover.c -lpthread");
FILE *cmd = popen("pidof -s Rover", "r");

fgets(line, LEN, cmd);
pid_t pid = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);
pclose(cmd);

printf("check");
if(pid == 0){
    system("xterm -e ./Rover");
    sleep(1);

    cmd = popen("pidof -s Rover", "r");
    fgets(line, LEN, cmd);
    pid = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);fflush(stdout);
    //pclose(cmd2);
    system("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in

```
system("xterm -e ./Rover");
```

This call makes the terminal to call `xterm` and then wait on it.

To verify it, just run `xterm` from your terminal and you will notice that your own terminal will freeze.

One solution which I can thought is to create a child process and call xterm from there.

```
pid_t test = fork();
if(!test){
    system("xterm -e ./Rover");
} else {
   //Rest of your task.

}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to open Rover in a separate console. (If you check, I do that inside the if.  
system("xterm -e ./Rover");

Comment: Thanks, that solved the main problem. I'll have to rewrite most of the code now, but you're awesome.